# How to allow spaces in url query string in aiohttp

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am trying out aiohttp and wanted have a url where say one of the values in the query string is `AB CD` so my url is `servername/index/ab cd` where index is the handler and prints whatever the value is passed.

In flask we do `<path:name>`. How do we do it in AioHttp? `{path:name}` doesn't work for obvious reasons.

Below is the code:

```
async def index(request):
    name = request.match_info.get('name', "Anonymous")
    txt = "Hello {}\n".format(name)
    return web.Response(text=txt)

app = web.Application()
app.router.add_get('/{name}', index)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.run_app(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works already.

Just try `http://127.0.0.1:8080/John%20Doe` on your server snippet.

Comment: Does the client have to encode it or server needs to encode the query params? As I see %20 added automatically in the request if I don't add it.

Comment: Correct client should percent encode data -- browsers do it for example. On server side aiohttp does *requote* received path anyway -- as any correct server should do (for example Django or Flask).